# Python's equivalent to Ruby's File.read method

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to read the contents of a file in a single method call.

I don't want to have to worry about opening the file, reading from the file, and then closing the file (3 method calls).

I just want the content.

In ruby, there is File.read("/path/to/file"), which returns the contents of that file and properly closes it. Is there an equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate two instructions to get the same behaviour :/. But then the file isn't properly closed.

```
file = open("/path/to/file","r").read()
```

edit:
Best option as far as I know leaves you needing 2/3 you mention. Just use the with statement so you don't have to worry about closing said file.

```
with open("/path/to/file","r") as file:
   text = file.read()
```

Comment: Should there also be a try/finally block?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Context Manager in Python, which is available from Python 2.5.

```
with open('yourfile') as f:
   contents = f.read()
```

It will automatically, open and close the file for you. The default mode is 'r' which stands for reading.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function included with Python. It's simple enough to define one, though.

```
def read_whole_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()
```